# Postgres - Optimized dynamic headers in separate table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    header_1 text NOT NULL,
    header_2 text,
    header_3 text );

CREATE TABLE headers (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    header_type text NOT NULL,
    organization_id bigint );


INSERT INTO contacts 
(id, header_1, header_2, header_3) 
VALUES 
(1,'bob1@hotmail.com','Bob1','lol'), 
(2,'bob2@hotmail.com','Bob2','lol'), 
(3,'bob3@hotmail.com','Bob3','lol'), 
(4,'bob4@hotmail.com','Bob4','lol'), 
(5,'bob5@hotmail.com','Bob5','lol');

INSERT INTO headers
(id, name, header_type, organization_id) 
VALUES 
(1,'Email','email', 1), 
(2,'First Name','first_name', 1), 
(3,'Last Name','last_name', 1);
```

I wanna end up with this structure, the **tricky part is that the headers are dynamic, meaning there can be n amount of headers**, "contacts" columns will always start with 'header_' and "headers" will always match the contact id,

```
Email             | First Name | Last Name 
------------------|------------|-----------
bob1@hotmail.com  | Bob1       | lol
bob2@hotmail.com  | Bob2       | lol
bob3@hotmail.com  | Bob3       | lol
bob4@hotmail.com  | Bob4       | lol
bob5@hotmail.com  | Bob5       | lol
```

Optimized querys are prefered

EDIT: Just to clarify
1.- There can be n amount of contact tables (contact1, contact2, etc)
2.- There can be n amount of rows in both header and contact tables.
3.- You can asume the data will always be integral, if table "contacts24" has a column named "header_57", you can asume theres gonna be a row in headers table with id: 57

Comment: It looks like you are looking for an EAV-model, but just did not get it.

Comment: When I came to the job this was their structure T_T

Answer (score 0):

At SQL, the table can not have a different number of columns for each row. So, it means you can not have a dynamic count of `headers` for each row on your `contacts` table.

Comment: In this project, there´s different tables of contacts, so "contacts1" could have different columns as "columns2"

Comment: @BobXplosion and each `contacts[x]` table will have only one row?

Comment: No, they can have n amount of rows